# How to find minimum, maximum and average value from a Generic ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, switch-statement

I have 3 classes Pet, Cat and Dog classes. Cat and Dog classes are childs of Pet class and I've overrided toString method. The toString method that I overrided in Dog class prints the name field and weight field of Dog class. I've created an ArrayList called mainList and **I need a method which calculates minimum, maximum and avarage value of weights in ArrayList.** *Can you tell me how can I create a method that calculates minimum, maximum and avarage values of weights of Dog Objects in ArrayList?*

My classes are down below...

Pet Class:

```
public class Pet
{
    private String name;



    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    protected void setName(String newName)
    {
        name = newName;
    }

    public Pet(String petName) {
        name = petName;
    }
}
```

Dog Class:

```
public class Dog extends Pet
{

    private Double weight;

    public double getWeight()
    {
        return weight;
    }

    protected void setWeight(double newWeight)
    {
        weight = newWeight;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return String.format("%s , %f", getName(), getWeight());
    }

    public Dog(String petName, double dogWeight)
    {
        super(petName);
        weight = dogWeight;

    }
}
```

PetTest Class:

```
import java.util.*;

public class PetTest
{
    static ArrayList<Pet> mainList = new ArrayList<Pet>();
    static Iterator<Pet> mainIter = mainList.iterator();
    static Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void eighthCase()
    {
      // I need a method here
    }

    public static void listThemAll()
    {
        for(Pet pet: mainList)
        {
            System.out.println(pet.toString());
        }
    }

    public static void listDogs()
    {
            for(Pet pet: mainList)
            {
                if (pet instanceof Dog)
                {
                    System.out.println(pet.toString());
                }
            }//end of for loop
    }//end of listDogs method

    public static void listCats()
    {
            for(Pet pet: mainList)
            {
                if(pet instanceof Cat)
                {
                    System.out.println(pet.toString());
                }
            }//end of for loop

    }//end of listCats method

    public static void addDog(String dogName,Double dogWeight)
    {
        Pet dog = new Dog(dogName, dogWeight);
        mainList.add(dog);
    }//end of addDog method

    public static void addCat(String catName, String furColor)
    {
        Pet cat = new Cat(catName, furColor);
        mainList.add(cat);
    }//end of addCat method

    public static void removeDog(String dogName)
    {
        for(Pet pet : mainList)
            {
                if((pet instanceof Dog) && (pet.getName().equals(dogName)))
                {
                    mainList.remove(pet);
                }//end of if statement
            }//end of for loop

    }//end of removeDog method


    public static void removeCat(String catName)
    {
            for(Pet pet : mainList)
            {
                if((pet instanceof Cat) && (pet.getName().equals(catName)))
                {
                    mainList.remove(pet);

                }//end of if statement

            }//end of for loop

    }//end of removeCat method

    public static void showMenu()
    {
        System.out.println("1. Add dog ");
        System.out.println("2. Add cat");
        System.out.println("3. Remove dog");
        System.out.println("4. Remove cat");
        System.out.println("5. List dogs");
        System.out.println("6. List cats");
        System.out.println("7. List all pets");
        System.out.println("8. Show min, max and average weight of dogs");
        System.out.println("0. Quit");
        int action = keyboard.nextInt();

        Scanner parameter1 = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner parameter2 = new Scanner(System.in);

        while(action > 0 && action <= 8)
        {
        switch(action)
        {
        case 1: 
            System.out.println("Type in the name of the dog that you want to add.");
            String dogName = parameter1.next();
            System.out.println("Type in the weight of the dog that you want to add.");
            Double dogWeight = parameter2.nextDouble();
            addDog(dogName,dogWeight);
            showMenu();

            break;

        case 2:
            System.out.println("Type in the name of the cat that you want to add.");
            String catName = parameter1.next();
            System.out.println("Type in the color of the cat that you want to add.");
            String furColor = parameter2.next();
            addCat(catName,furColor);
            showMenu();

            break;

        case 3:
            System.out.println("Type in the name of dog that you want to remove.");
            String dogToRemove = parameter1.next();
            removeDog(dogToRemove);
            showMenu();

            break;

        case 4:
            System.out.println("Type in the name of dog that you want to remove.");
            String catToRemove = parameter1.next();
            removeDog(catToRemove);
            showMenu();

            break;

        case 5:
            listDogs();
            showMenu();

            break;

        case 6:
            listCats();
            showMenu();
            break;

        case 7:
            listThemAll();
            showMenu();
            break;

        case 8:
            eighthCase();
            break;


        }//end of switch statement

        }//end of while loop
    }//end of showMenu method

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        showMenu();



        }//end of main method



}//end of the class
```

Comment: The problem you're going to run into is that getWeight isn't part of the Pet class.

Comment: Collections.min and Collections.max will help, as for the average that shouldn't be too difficult, write your own average method. list_sum/list_size

Comment: You should really get rid of `mainIter`. It isn't used anywhere, and it doesn't make any sense to keep an `Iterator` around like this, since they can only be used once, and you can get one from the `List` any time you want. Also, you should declare `mainList` as `List<Pet>`, not `ArrayList<Pet>`. *Program to the interface, not the implementation*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it like this (bottom one is shorter):

```
public static void calculateDogValues(){
    List<Double> dogWeightList = new ArrayList<>();
    double max = 0, min = 0, average = 0;
       for(Pet pet: mainList){
          if (pet instanceof Dog){    //add all dog weights to list
              dogWeightList.add(pet.getWeight());
          }
       }

       Collections.sort(dogWeightList);   //sort the list
       min = dogWeightList.get(0);   //get smallest value
       max = dogWeightList.get(dogWeightList.size()-1);   //get highest value

       for (double weight : dogWeightList) {   //make sum of all weights
          average += weight;
       }
       average = average/dogWeightList.size();   //sum/number of weights

       System.out.println("Minimum weight is " + min);
       System.out.println("Maximum weight is " + max);
       System.out.println("Average weight is " + average);

    }
```

Or like this without sort:

```
    double max = 0, min = 0, average = 0, amountOfDogs = 0;
       for(Pet dog: mainList){
          if (dog instanceof Dog){   
              min = Math.min(min, dog.getWeight()); 
              max = Math.max(max, dog.getWeight());
              average += dog.getWeight();
              amountOfDogs++;
          }
       }
       average = average/amountOfDogs;

       System.out.println("Minimum weight is " + min);
       System.out.println("Maximum weight is " + max);
       System.out.println("Average weight is " + average);

    }
```

Also make your pet class this:

```
public class Pet{

    private String name;
    private double weight;

    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    protected void setName(String newName)
    {
        name = newName;
    }

    public Pet(String petName) {
        name = petName;
    }

    public void setWeight(double newWeight){
    weight = newWeight;
    }

    public double getWeight(){
    return weight;
    }
}
```

There was no weight in superclass.

Comment: Absolutely unnecessary to sort here. You just get O(n log n) instead of original O(n) complexity.

Comment: @ginz There are numerous ways, I added another without sort.

Comment: Please, define and initialize all of `min`, `max`, `average` and `amountOfDogs`.

Comment: @ginz We are not supposed to be feeding with spoons here :/

Comment: Of course, but you code should be correct in the sense of correctness and design. There, say, `max` is initialized with 0, which is incorrect as all the values might be negative, so it should be initialized with `Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY`, same for `min` (only `Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY`). Also, these values stays the same for the different calls of the methods and they're collect the old values, which also lead to incorrect behavior. And so on.

Comment: The values will not be negative. Common sense is also used in design and dogs can't weigh less than 0. You are right about the other part but like I said, I am not trying to write the code for him, just give a general idea of what to do. Hence where is the learning aspect.

Comment: @Noxob Ginz is using int in his code example. While you are using doubles. This is why it gives an exception. Now you should correct yours too ginz.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52709/discussion-between-crashystar-and-ginz)

Comment: Your codes working fine with little bit edit Thank you! :) (I fixed the problem that the switch statement makes method act like an infinite loop, I added showMenu method to 8th case and now it works.)

Comment: @Noxob Good to hear :)

Answer (score 1):

In Java 8 this can be done with `Stream`s:

```
mainList.stream()
    .filter (animal -> animal instanceof Dog)
    .mapToDouble(animal -> ((Dog)animal).getWeight())
    .min()
    //.max()
    //.average()
    .get()
```

And you may get the same result with Java 7:

```
List<Dog> dogs = new ArrayList<>();
for (Animal animal : mainList)
    if (animal instanceof Dog)
        dogs.add((Dog)animal);

double min = dogs.get(0).getWeight();
double max = dogs.get(0).getWeight();
double sum = 0;
for (Dog dog : dogs) {
    min = Math.min(min, dog.getWeight());
    max = Math.max(max, dog.getWeight());
    sum += dog.getWeight();
}
System.out.format("min = %i, max = %i, average = %f%n", min, max, sum * 1.0 / dogs.size());
// or by implementing comparator
Comparator <Dog> dogComparator = new Comparator<>() {
    public int compare (Dog dog1, Dog dog2) {
        return Double.compare(dog1.getWeight(), dog2.getWeight());
    }
};
double min = Collections.min(dogs, dogComparator).getWeight();
double max = Collections.max(dogs, dogComparator).getWeight();
```

Comment: I've changed my eighthCase method like that:   public static void eighthCase()
 {
  List<Dog> dogs = new ArrayList<Dog>();
  for (Pet animal : mainList)
      if (animal instanceof Dog)
          dogs.put((Dog)animal);
  int min = dogs.get(0);
  int max = dogs.get(0);
  int sum = 0;
  for (Dog dog : dogs) {
      min = Math.min(min, dog.getWeight());
      max = Math.max(max, dog.getWeight());
      sum += dog.getWeight();
  }
  System.out.format("min = %i, max = %i, average = %f%n", min, max, sum * 1.0 / dogs.size());
 }   but im still having exception...

Comment: What exception do you have?

Comment: In eclipse, it shows so much mistaken places and when i fix it, It shows another mistaken places. like that [Photo](http://i.imgur.com/K9hOTWE.jpg)

Comment: java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
 The method put(Dog) is undefined for the type List<Dog>
 Type mismatch: cannot convert from Dog to int
 Type mismatch: cannot convert from Dog to int
 Type mismatch: cannot convert from double to int
 Type mismatch: cannot convert from double to int
 The type new Comparator(){} must implement the inherited abstract method Comparator.compare(Object, Object)
 Type mismatch: cannot convert from boolean to int
 Duplicate local variable min
 Type mismatch: cannot convert from double to int
 Duplicate local variable max

Comment: Fixed `put` with `add`, also fixed `Comparator` generic init

Comment: I bothered you so much I am sorry :/ but it has errors at dogs.get(0) it says The dogs List includes only Dog element you can't assign it to a double. How can i solve it?